# disabled browser refresh button in angular 12

Tags: angular14

I want to disabled browser refresh button for my angular web pages i am using angular 12 version and tried some of solustions from the google and youtube but it is sufficient for version14

Comment: You can't disable this, this would lead to a horrible user experience if this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with simple JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
e = e || window.event;
if(e.keyCode == 116){
    e.preventDefault();
}});
```